# No Camera Found: Ubuntu 20.04 on 2015 MacBook Air

Tags: webcam, macbook

I have installed Linux 20.04.1, 5.11.0-41-generic on a 2015 MacBook Air. It does not see the camera. I ran cheese and got "no device found."

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

''''

```
(cheese:5086): cheese-CRITICAL **: 14:57:03.964: cheese_camera_device_get_name: assertion 'CHEESE_IS_CAMERA_DEVICE (device)' failed

(cheese:5086): GLib-CRITICAL **: 14:57:03.964: g_variant_new_string: assertion 'string != NULL' failed

(cheese:5086): GLib-CRITICAL **: 14:57:03.964: g_variant_ref_sink: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:5086): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 14:57:03.964: g_settings_schema_key_type_check: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:5086): GLib-CRITICAL **: 14:57:03.964: g_variant_get_type_string: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:5086): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 14:57:03.964: g_settings_set_value: key 'camera' in 'org.gnome.Cheese' expects type 's', but a GVariant of type '(null)' was given

(cheese:5086): GLib-CRITICAL **: 14:57:03.964: g_variant_unref: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

** (cheese:5086): CRITICAL **: 14:57:03.964: cheese_preferences_dialog_setup_resolutions_for_device: assertion 'device != NULL' failed '''
```

Comment: It should appear with `sudo lshw -C video`. If `ls -l /dev/video*` shows group access is allowed, I have an answer.

Comment: This worked: https://askubuntu.com/a/1432776/925128 Cheese didn't work but Kamoso did.